# Can I share a HTML file that is in my computer?

Tags: html, facebook, share

Assume that I have a HTML file as myweb.html in C:\ directory. And some texts in it. So can I share it on Facebook just as we share a webpage? And how?

I pasted it into somewhere in my page c:\myweb.html:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=" title="Share this webspage on Facebook">Share on Facebook</a>
```

I think it will share the page itself. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, files on your computer are private and not accessible to other people (with some exceptions).  If you want to share your html file, you need to first upload it to a web server.

Comment: To be more precise, I have some texts in a html file. So is there anyway to share it except of "copying and pasting" it, again just as we share a webpage that I mentioned above? How can some offline games share its score to facebook, it firstly uploads your score to somewhere and then share it? I just want to share the text in my html.

Comment: I believe facebook requires you to have some form of web URL when you share something.  If you have a static IP address, you can run a web server on your computer and share the file that way; otherwise, you'll have to periodically upload the text to a web server and share it there.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your file is a web page that can be accessed from outside of your network, then no, you cannot share it.